# How to update price by Ajax based on range selection for my variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this product that has very many variables, and i'm trying to represent them as range sliders instead of selects, using the method here: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms

You can see my predicament here: http://rt2.flywheelsites.com/produkt/smavarereol/

---

The problem I'm having is, that while it works and the correct item gets added to the cart, I'm having issues having the Price update at each step of the Range slider. Is there anything I could possibly add to make it wake up and update? When I use the Select (which I've made visible for this example) they update just fine, just not so much with the range slider.

Ideas?

Below is my JS, for one of the range inputs, they are all like this

Anything you could tell? I'm a bit lost at the moment, as I'm not quite up on my Ajax skills on how to push the updated range selection to Ajax to update the price.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var select = $("#pa_antall-seksjoner-i-lengden");
  var slider = $("<div id='slider1'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 11,
    range: "min",
    value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
    }
  });
  $("#pa_antall-seksjoner-i-lengden").on("change", function() {
    slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var select = $("#pa_seksjonslengde");
  var slider = $("<div id='slider2'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 3,
    range: "min",
    value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
    }
  });
  $("#pa_seksjonslengde").on("change", function() {
    slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var select = $("#pa_dybde");
  var slider = $("<div id='slider3'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    range: "min",
    value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
    }
  });
  $("#pa_dybde").on("change", function() {
    slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var select = $("#pa_belastning-pr-hylle");
  var slider = $("<div id='slider4'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 3,
    range: "min",
    value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
    }
  });
  $("#pa_belastning-pr-hylle").on("change", function() {
    slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
  });
});


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var select = $("#pa_hoyde");
  var slider = $("<div id='slider5'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 4,
    range: "min",
    value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
    }
  });
  $("#pa_hoyde").on("change", function() {
    slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var select = $("#pa_antall-hyller-i-hoyden");
  var slider = $("<div id='slider6'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    range: "min",
    value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
    }
  });
  $("#pa_antall-hyller-i-hoyden").on("change", function() {
    slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_antall-seksjoner-i-lengden">Antall seksjoner i lengden</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_antall-seksjoner-i-lengden" class="" name="attribute_pa_antall-seksjoner-i-lengden" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_antall-seksjoner-i-lengden" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Velg ett alternativ</option>
          <option value="1-stk">1 stk</option>
          <option value="2-stk">2 stk</option>
          <option value="3-stk">3 stk</option>
          <option value="4-stk">4 stk</option>
          <option value="5-stk">5 stk</option>
          <option value="6-stk">6 stk</option>
          <option value="7-stk">7 stk</option>
          <option value="8-stk">8 stk</option>
          <option value="9-stk">9 stk</option>
          <option value="10-stk">10 stk</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_seksjonslengde">Seksjonslengde</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_seksjonslengde" class="" name="attribute_pa_seksjonslengde" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_seksjonslengde" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Velg ett alternativ</option>
          <option value="1000mm">1000mm</option>
          <option value="1300mm">1300mm</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_hoyde">Høyde</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_hoyde" class="" name="attribute_pa_hoyde" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_hoyde" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Velg ett alternativ</option>
          <option value="2000mm">2000mm</option>
          <option value="2500mm">2500mm</option>
          <option value="3000mm">3000mm</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_dybde">Dybde</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_dybde" class="" name="attribute_pa_dybde" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_dybde" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Velg ett alternativ</option>
          <option value="300mm">300mm</option>
          <option value="400mm">400mm</option>
          <option value="500mm">500mm</option>
          <option value="600mm">600mm</option>
          <option value="800mm">800mm</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_antall-hyller-i-hoyden">Antall hyller i høyden</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_antall-hyller-i-hoyden" class="" name="attribute_pa_antall-hyller-i-hoyden" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_antall-hyller-i-hoyden" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Velg ett alternativ</option>
          <option value="4-hyller">4 hyller</option>
          <option value="5-hyller">5 hyller</option>
          <option value="6-hyller">6 hyller</option>
          <option value="7-hyller">7 hyller</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_belastning-pr-hylle">Belastning pr hylle</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_belastning-pr-hylle" class="" name="attribute_pa_belastning-pr-hylle" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_belastning-pr-hylle" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Velg ett alternativ</option>
          <option value="100kg">100kg</option>
          <option value="200kg">200kg</option>
        </select>


    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="single_variation_wrap">
  <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="display: block;">
<div class="woocommerce-variation-description"></div>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span>XXXX ,-</span></span></div>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability"></div>
</div><div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">

 <div class="quantity">
   <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5e8ae5b2dbbce">Småvarereol antall</label>
 <input type="number" id="quantity_5e8ae5b2dbbce" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Antall" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
  </div>

<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Kjøp</button>


<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="3615">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="3615">
<input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="4373">
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Simply add an new EventListener?

Comment: Updated with the complete .js file I have for it, and added the requirements from Jquery UI if that helps.

Comment: Also, I'd imagine that it's not so much updating the price, but more updating the variation choices by Ajax, so the choice gets updated and also the picture, should there be one for that variation.

Comment: Great. Now we need to code and HTML for the price. It is hard to fix your price calculation if we do not see it

Comment: I get an alert telling be to make a product selection before I add to the cart

Comment: If you check the linked relevant product page, you can see the price updating when the Select are used, just not when the Range slider is used. 

I could probably update the HTML and all here, but without the price values hidden in the product variations, it wouldn't get you far I think? Either way, let me fetch the relevant code.

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected the range sliders look fine and all, but they don't seem to be actually doing the work I want them to do. Work fine with the selects though. Which is a nice backup solution, but I'd love to get this working.

Comment: How do I get to the "inked relevant product page,"

Comment: Why is there no price field on the page where you select the stuff?

Comment: Hey, apprecriate you looking into and helping me still. It's here on this page: http://rt2.flywheelsites.com/produkt/smavarereol/ 

The price appears when you use the Select input, sadly not the range slider. Look above the add to cart button when all inputs have a value.